# Pinterest : data-pinmedia does not override source

Tags: pinterest

I'm using Pinterest for my web site here : http://www.encadrement-art.com/galerie.htm

My source image is a thumb image, so the "pin it" button does not show any image in this page.

But when I use the `data-pin-media` attribute (for the first image in this page), the "pin it" button does not show the image yet.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Read this

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/?

Comment: I have read the instructions prior to post my message here

Comment: My Thumb Image is Under than 100 x 100 px. If she is over the "Pint It Button Works". The data-pin-media attribute does not works. It never override the original image.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to have the full path in data-pin-media, not the relative path, eg `<img src="./01-min.jpg" data-pin-media="http://www.example.com/01-min.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help .... but it does not works ... :(

The minimum size of my src image must be 200X200px ... al my thunmbnail are in 150x150px :(